# perl-DBI / perl-DBD-oracle installation

Tags: perl, oracle

What I want to do is connecting and retrieving data from oracle database through perl.

What i did(as oracle account) is like below.....

```
$ rpm -qa|grep DBI
perl-DBI-1.52-2.el5

$ wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.17.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf DBD-Oracle-1.17.tar.gz
$ cd DBD-Oracle-1.17
$ perl Makefile.PL
Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.008008 on linux (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Using Oracle in /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1002000500" (CHAR)
Oracle version 10.2.0.5 (10.2)
Found /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Using /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to '/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib:/usr/lib:/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib32:.'
Reading /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk
Reading /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk

Attempting to discover Oracle OCI build rules
gcc    -c -o DBD_ORA_OBJ.o DBD_ORA_OBJ.c
by executing: [make -f /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo/demo_rdbms.mk build ECHODO=echo ECHO=echo GENCLNTSH='echo genclntsh' CC=true OPTIMIZE= CCFLAGS= EXE=DBD_ORA_EXE OBJS=DBD_ORA_OBJ.o]
Oracle oci build command:
    [true -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/lib/ -o DBD_ORA_EXE DBD_ORA_OBJ.o -lclntsh   `cat /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/sysliblist` -ldl -lm  -lpthread]

Found header files in /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public.

Checking for functioning wait.ph
Constant subroutine __USE_POSIX undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 8.
Constant subroutine __USE_POSIX2 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 9.
Constant subroutine __USE_POSIX199309 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 10.
Constant subroutine __USE_POSIX199506 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 11.
Constant subroutine __USE_XOPEN undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 12.
Constant subroutine __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 13.
Constant subroutine __USE_UNIX98 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 14.
Constant subroutine __USE_LARGEFILE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 16.
Constant subroutine __USE_LARGEFILE64 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 17.
Constant subroutine __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 18.
Constant subroutine __USE_BSD undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 19.
Constant subroutine __USE_SVID undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 20.
Constant subroutine __USE_MISC undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 21.
Constant subroutine __USE_GNU undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 23.
Constant subroutine __USE_REENTRANT undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 24.
Constant subroutine _POSIX_SOURCE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 49.
Constant subroutine _POSIX_C_SOURCE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 51.
Constant subroutine _XOPEN_SOURCE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 53.
Constant subroutine _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 55.
Constant subroutine _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 57.
Constant subroutine _LARGEFILE_SOURCE undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 104.
Constant subroutine __USE_ISOC99 undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 108.
Constant subroutine __GNU_LIBRARY__ undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/features.ph line 156.
Operator or semicolon missing before &__inline at (eval 167) line 1.
Ambiguous use of & resolved as operator & at (eval 167) line 1.
Constant subroutine __need_size_t undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/stddef.ph line 148.
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 241) line 1, near "'int'  $__val"
    (Missing operator before   $__val?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 245) line 1, near ") 0"
    (Missing operator before 0?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 246) line 1, near ") 1"
    (Missing operator before 1?)
Number found where operator expected at (eval 247) line 1, near ") 2"
    (Missing operator before 2?)
Constant subroutine __need_timespec undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/time.ph line 49.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at (eval 447) line 1.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at (eval 448) line 1.
Constant subroutine __need_timeval undefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/bits/time.ph line 23.


System: perl5.008008 linux builder10.centos.org 2.6.18-53.el5 #1 smp mon nov 12 02:14:55 est 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux 
Compiler:   gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm
Linker:     /usr/bin/ld
Sysliblist: -ldl -lm -lpthread -lnsl -lirc 
Oracle makefiles would have used these definitions but we override them:
  CC:       $(COMPDIR)/bin/gcc
  CFLAGS:   $(GFLAG) $(OPTIMIZE) $(CDEBUG) $(CCFLAGS) $(PFLAGS)\
    $(SHARED_CFLAG) $(USRFLAGS)
           [$(GFLAG) -O3 $(CDEBUG) -m32 -trigraphs -fPIC -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/plsql/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/network/public -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -DSLTS_ENABLE -DSLMXMX_ENABLE -D_REENTRANT -DNS_THREADS -fno-strict-aliasing $(LPFLAGS) $(USRFLAGS)]
  LDFLAGS:  $(LDFLAGS32)
           [-m32 -o $@ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms//lib32/ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib32/ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib32/stubs/]
Linking with OTHERLDFLAGS = -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/lib/   -lclntsh   `cat /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/sysliblist` -ldl -lm  -lpthread [from 'build' rule]

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
LD_RUN_PATH=/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib:/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/lib
Using DBD::Oracle 1.17.
Using DBD::Oracle 1.17.
Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::Oracle

***  If you have problems...
     read all the log printed above, and the README and README.help.txt files.
     (Of course, you have read README by now anyway, haven't you?)

$ make
cp Oracle.pm blib/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm
cp oraperl.ph blib/lib/oraperl.ph
cp dbdimp.h blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/dbdimp.h
cp ocitrace.h blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/ocitrace.h
cp Oraperl.pm blib/lib/Oraperl.pm
cp Oracle.h blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.h
cp lib/DBD/Oracle/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/Oracle/GetInfo.pm
cp mk.pm blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/mk.pm
/usr/bin/perl -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Oracle/g" /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/Driver.xst > Oracle.xsi
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Oracle.xs > Oracle.xsc && mv Oracle.xsc Oracle.c
gcc -c  -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/plsql/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/network/public -I/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"1.17\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.17\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DNEW_OCI_INIT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"10.2.0.5\" Oracle.c
Oracle.c: In function 'XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_append':
Oracle.xs:201: warning: unused variable 'startp'
gcc -c  -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/plsql/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/network/public -I/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"1.17\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.17\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DNEW_OCI_INIT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"10.2.0.5\" dbdimp.c
dbdimp.c: In function 'ora_db_login6':
dbdimp.c:652: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c: In function 'dbd_rebind_ph_char':
dbdimp.c:1052: warning: value computed is not used
gcc -c  -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/demo -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/plsql/public -I/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/network/public -I/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"1.17\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.17\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DNEW_OCI_INIT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"10.2.0.5\" oci8.c
oci8.c: In function 'fetch_func_rset':
oci8.c:626: warning: value computed is not used
oci8.c: In function 'dbd_rebind_ph_lob':
oci8.c:711: warning: value computed is not used
oci8.c: In function 'ora_blob_read_mb_piece':
oci8.c:778: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
oci8.c: In function 'ora_describe':
oci8.c:1267: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
oci8.c: In function 'post_execute_lobs':
oci8.c:2118: warning: value computed is not used
oci8.c: At top level:
oci8.c:563: warning: 'fetch_func_nty' defined but not used
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::Oracle ()
chmod 644 Oracle.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic Oracle.o dbdimp.o oci8.o -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/ -L/sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/rdbms/lib/   -lclntsh   `cat /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/sysliblist` -ldl -lm  -lpthread -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so    \
            \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
cp Oracle.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bs
/usr/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" ora_explain.PL ora_explain
Extracted ora_explain from ora_explain.PL with variable substitutions.
cp ora_explain blib/script/ora_explain
/usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::MY" -e "MY->fixin(shift)" blib/script/ora_explain
Manifying blib/man1/ora_explain.1
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Oracle.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::Oraperl.3pm

$ make install


Warning: You do not have permissions to install into /usr/share/man/man1 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 114.
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Writing /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Oracle/.packlist
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod

$ sudo - chmod 777 /usr/share/man

Warning: You do not have permissions to install into /usr/bin at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 114.
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Writing /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Oracle/.packlist
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod

$ sudo - chmod 777 /usr/bin

Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Writing /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Oracle/.packlist
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod

$ perl -e 'use DBD::Oracle'
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/libnnz10.so:  cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at (eval 3) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at ./ora_dump.pl line 7
```

I've checked permission of /sw/oracle/app/oracle/product/102/lib/libnnz10.so.
My machine is on CentOS release 5.5 and 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with SELinux. Try disabling it and see if this resolves your problem:
http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Comment: Thanks for your help... Unfortunatly,  the server must not be rebooted.

Comment: @KIM, just and FYI, but you can disable selinux with the following command line: setenforce 0

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you are missing and where you are going wrong. But I always follow below method and it has worked 100% times for me. Try this method and if it does not work, then I can definitely make it work for you....

One thing I notice in your post is that you are getting permissions issues. Try running these steps as root.

My environment: Oracle 11G running on remote box

My desktop: ubunt/fedora/RHEL/CenOS

I have implemented this on all above 4 flavors of Linux and they all work perfectly.

**Here are the steps (Follow 'em the sequence given):**

Install Perl DBI module

install below 3 rpm for oracle instant client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

```
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1 
oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1 
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1
```

I am using 64 bit linux box, so choose your RPM accordingly.

set below variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib 
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

also add `ORACLE_HOME` to your `PATH` variable

download `DBD::Oracle ver 1.44` from CPAN.
untar the module and run below commands in given sequence:

```
perl Makefile.PL 
make make 
install
```

DONE !!!